# How could I format content before comparing two xml files?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application I store model information as XML in a number of files. These files can be managed by SVN in a remote repository. The XML format is compressed on to one line which makes it essentially impossible to compare the local file with the one in SVN.

I am wondering if it is possible to temporarily format both files before displaying them in the compare editor. No merge or saving is necessary. It is just useful to see what has been changed.

Comment: as a workaround I now 'pretty print' the XML and have registered the file types as simple text.

Comment: I fail to discern the actual question. Do you mean something like "is there a way to have Eclipse automacitally format the local XML file which represents a part of model of an RCP application so that I could compare it with the version of this file managed by Subversion?"

Comment: Another question is: are these XML files keps in Subversion in the compressed form as well?

Comment: @kostix SVN should return the files exactly as they were saved. I would like to intercept the files before they are compared and 'prettify' both before passing them to the compare editor. My goal is just to display changes to the XML content.

Comment: I'm afraid that [no, there's no direct way to do that](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201209.mbox/%3c504DED42.9090604@free.fr%3e): basically you have these options: 1) normalize before committing; 2) use a custom pre-processing step before diffing; 3) set up an external diff tool which could be a script doing (2) and then spawning a diff tool. Since you appear to use Eclipse for diffing, I'm afraid (2) is the only option.

Comment: @kostix (2) is what my question is about. Any ideas how to do it? (1) I have done already but costs ca 25% in file size and doesn't help with the '000s of items already stored. I thought I might be able to use some extension point to link myself into the CompareEditor somehow.

Comment: I'd say write a script which calls something like [`xmlstarlet fo <infile.xml >outfile.xml`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar) on the files and then runs the diffing tool on the generated files. (On GNU/Linux-based systems that thing usually cames prepackaged so you could do something like `apt install xmlstarlet`).